# Observe when div is hidden or shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<div class="test-tube uk-align-left uk-hidden-small">
  <div class="test-tube-bg uk-align-center">
    <canvas id="test-tube" class="substance" width="25" height="230" style=""></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where I need to trigger a Javascript method when the `<canvas>` or div with given id is either hidden or shown which will happen during screen resizing (hence u`k-hidden-small`), can this be done in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that with jQuery with something like this.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   if($('.uk-hidden-small').is(':hidden')) {
   //code to run when it's hidden
   } else {
   //code to run when it's shown (if necessary)
   }
});
```